# Interpreting the Coefficients of a Negative Binomial Regression Analysis

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, negative-binomial-distribution

I have built a negative binomial regression model in R, that looks at the relationship of between the number of times a radio ad was played (this is called TaImpacts) and the number of New Users on a website. The Region in which the ads were played is also used as an intervening variable.

All of this was done using the glm.nb() function from the "MASS" package.

Here is an example of the data used:

```
> head(test1)
         date      Region Activity   DayPart Users NewUsers RequestQuote BookAppointment RequestCallback BrPosted BrDownload Total.Goals AaImpacts TaImpacts
85 23/09/2019 EAST ANGLIA   During Afternoon   186      111            4               1               0        0          0           5      0.00      0.00
86 23/09/2019 EAST ANGLIA   During   Evening   111       80            1               0               0        0          0           1      0.00      0.00
87 23/09/2019 EAST ANGLIA   During   Morning   151       94            5               2               2        0          0           9      0.00      0.00
88 24/09/2019 EAST ANGLIA   During Afternoon   164       96            7               4               0        0          1          12 123467.27  46401.20
89 24/09/2019 EAST ANGLIA   During   Evening    97       64            5               1               1        1          0           8  13409.08   2539.30
90 24/09/2019 EAST ANGLIA   During   Morning   148       98            7               2               1        2          2          14 252867.20  68243.25
```

And here is the defined model and its outputs:

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = test1$NewUsers ~ test1$TaImpacts:test1$Region, 
    data = test1, link = log, init.theta = 4.630874902)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.3768  -0.7898  -0.1463   0.3396   3.0358  

Coefficients:
                                                                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                                              5.216e+00  3.777e-02 138.096  < 2e-16 ***
test1$TaImpacts:test1$RegionCENTRAL EAST                                -3.261e-07  9.095e-07  -0.359     0.72    
test1$TaImpacts:test1$RegionCENTRAL WEST, CENTRAL, CENTRAL EAST, ANGLIA  1.172e-05  8.594e-07  13.636  < 2e-16 ***
test1$TaImpacts:test1$RegionEAST ANGLIA                                 -1.054e-05  1.553e-06  -6.787 1.14e-11 ***
test1$TaImpacts:test1$RegionSOUTH WEST                                  -8.843e-06  1.645e-06  -5.377 7.59e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(4.6309) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 714.56  on 347  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 358.63  on 343  degrees of freedom
AIC: 4053.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  4.631 
          Std. Err.:  0.348 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -4041.183
```

Looking at the coefficients, I can see that three of them are negative but when I plot the data using ggplot with the following code:

```
# Plot TA Impacts vs NewUsers By Region
ggplot(test1, aes(y=NewUsers, x=TaImpacts, colour=Region)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = glm.nb)
```

I end up with a plot where the fitted lines all show a positive slope:

[image: Plot of Radio Impacts vs New Website Users]

Would anyone be able to explain to me why this is, as from the negative coefficients, I would expect a negatively sloping line for each region other than "CENTRAL WEST, CENTRAL, CENTRAL EAST, ANGLIA"?

Thank you in advance!